# How to find the type of array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, arff

I am trying to write a code for converting CSV to ARFF. I import the values between each `","` to a cell of an array, for example a instance such as:

```
Monday,176,49,203,27,77,38,Second
```

is converted to:

```
['Monday', '176', '49', '203', '27', '77', '38', 'Second']
```

The problem is that Python recognize each cell as string and you can see the recognized types by Python for the example:

```
[<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>]
```

I am looking for a way to distinguish between nominal and numerical attributes?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python

Answer (score 3):

The best I can think of is something like this, using [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

def converter(x):
    try:
        val = ast.literal_eval(x)
        return val
    except ValueError:
        return x
```

which gives

```
>>> seq = ['Monday', '176', '49', '203', '27', '77', '38', 'Second']
>>> newseq = [converter(x) for x in seq]
>>> newseq
['Monday', 176, 49, 203, 27, 77, 38, 'Second']
>>> map(type, newseq)
[<type 'str'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'str'>]
```

The advantage of using `ast.literal_eval` is that it handles more cases in a nice fashion:

```
>>> seq = ['Monday', '12.3', '(1, 2.3)', '[2,"fred"]']
>>> newseq = [converter(x) for x in seq]
>>> newseq
['Monday', 12.3, (1, 2.3), [2, 'fred']]
```

Comment: A good solution if there is a need to support hex literals, tuple types etc. in the text file but a bit heavy handed IMO if the text file contains simple text and numbers. Still, +1

Comment: Well, the `isdigit` solutions will fail on negative numbers, or anything with a `+`, etc., so ISTM we might as well use the builtin.

Comment: I can always change the `isdigit` to check for the last digit though, that'll always work

Comment: @Volatility: what about `"7-Eleven"` or `"Super-8"`?

Comment: @DSM: That's a very good point. @Volatility: But now that'll fail for short float literals like `2.` which end with `.` but is still a valid float. But I agree, this isn't a deal breaker since down the line we are anyway trying to parse the input using `int` and `float`. So we can always return back the original chunk if the `float` conversion fails.

Comment: Lol @DSM is that even valid? But yeah, I guess properly error-proofing the code would make it messy

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in lst:
    try:
        int(i)
        #whatever you want to do
    except ValueError:
        #error handling
```

That will work, although from this would be much better:

```
for i in lst:
    if i[-1].isdigit():  #it is a number
        #whatever
    else:
        #whatever else
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354038/1907098)

See also: [str.isdigit() method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

Comment: Thanks - with this method everything is fine except of last cell that is recognized as string

Comment: @UNSWCSE isn't `'Second'` a string?

Comment: sorry!, it is recognized as number

Comment: @UNSWCSE I have no such problem, are you sure you've copied the code right?

Answer (score 1):

If performance matters a lot here, I'll try to adopt a three step approach. This approach needlessly avoids casting a string to `int` or `float` and then failing by using a simple check for the first character.

- For each chunk, check if the first character is a digit or not
- If it is, first try parsing it as an `int` and if it fails, parse it as `float`
- If all that fails, you have a big problem :)

Something like:

```
for chunk in chunks:
    if chunk[0].isdigit():
        try:
            return int(chunk)
        except ValueError:
            return float(chunk)
    else:
        # It's a string (a non-numeric entity)
        return chunk
```

You'll of course need a bit more special handling for supporting hex/oct literals in the text/csv file but I don't think that's a normal case for you?

**EDIT**: Come to think of it, [Volatility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179686/193906) has used a similar approach with the only difference being calling `isdigit` on the entire string instead of just the first character. This might take a wee bit more time if we have long numeric sequences in which `isdigit` is called on each and every char whereas my approach always checks for the first char so might be a bit faster.